# Questions about Moderntimeline in moderncv

Tags: moderncv, moderntimeline

Corresponding to [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54705/moderncv-with-moderntimeline-how-do-i-center-the-label-above-the-timeline) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83571/moderntimeline-alignment-of-text-on-start-and-end-of-bars) I tried to create a timeline in my cv. My code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm,headheight=21pt} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[firstyear=1996,lastyear=2013]{moderntimeline}


% for timeline

\makeatletter
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@textstartabove{\tl@width-2pt}
\NewDocumentCommand\tldatelabelcventryn{O{center}O{color1}mmmmmmm}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endyear{\tl@lastyear}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startfraction{(#3-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endfraction{(\tl@endyear-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline]{%
     \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex) rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
     \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
     \fill [#2] (0,0)
        ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [tl@startyear,yshift=5pt,anchor=#1] {#4}
        node {$\bullet$};
   }
}
{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}{#9}
}
\makeatother
%
\tltextstart[north]{\scriptsize}
\tltextend[south]{\scriptsize}

%
\firstname{C}
\familyname{N}
\title{Curriculum vit\ae{}}              
\address{}{}  
\photo[128pt]{picture}                        

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
born on .... in xxxxx

\section{school education}
\tlcventry[cyan!60!black]{2000}{2008}{test1}{test}{}{}{grade: 22}
\tlcventry[cyan!60!black]{1996}{2000}{test2}{}{}{}{test}
\section{studies}
\tllabelcventry[cyan!60!black]{2011}{2013}{Oct 01, 2011}{test3}{}{}{}{test}

\tldatelabelcventry[cyan!60!black]{2011}{Apr 06, 2011}{Test4}{}{test}
{test}{}


\tllabelcventry[cyan!60!black]{2009}{2011}{Dec 01,2009--Jan 01,2011}{Test5}{}{}{}{test}


\end{document}
```

This gives

[image: t1]

1. test1 and test2 are ok
2. I want to have test3 until today. So that the Oct 01, 2011 is below the line and it goes until today, so it should be `Oct01,2011--today`, but this is not working, also the descirption should be "today"
3. As you can see Test4 is (vertically) not centered? The bold Test4 is too much under the grey line, it is not the same as in the previous cases, how can I have this the way as before? Also I want to have the "Apr 06, 2011" above the grey line.
4. Test 5 does not work. How can I have the Jan 01, 2011 above the grey line.

And one general question: Currently I am only specifying the year, so e.g. 2009, although sometimes I add the specific day in the label. Is it possible to also specify the month, so that the cyan bar is drawn excatly at this month and this year, so to distinguish on this very detailed level?

EDIT:

```
\tllabelcventryn[cyan!60!black]{2000}{2008.583}{2000}{Jul 11, 2008}{Test}{Test}{}{}{grade: 1.8}
```

gives

[image: t1]

but I want to have the "Jul 11, 2008" shifted/pushed to the right, so like this (I did it with paint):

[image: t2]

EDIT 2: Further on, I would like to have the Apr 06, 2011 in the same style, so that the label is not centered about the timeline itself but around the dot, so that it looks like:

[image: te]

So it should have the same alignment as the others, in total they should end at the same border, so that it looks like the following:

[image: test1]

Comment: OK I found out the answer to my general question: Yes, with dots after the year, so for dec 01,2011 e.g. 2011.92.

Comment: I think if someone manages to get the "today" at the end of the timeline and above the grey line it will cover the text. So a next question would be: How can I increase the space between the date column and the text? I am not talking about the size of the date column (that would be e.g. \setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.15\textwidth}) but the space between the date column and the text column?

Comment: `\setlength{\separatorcolumnwidth}{1em}`, for example, allows you to change the space between the date column and the text column.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for this hint! I am still searching about solutions to my questions.....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution (notice the additional "n" at the end of the newly defined commands):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm,headheight=21pt} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[firstyear=1996,lastyear=2013]{moderntimeline}


% for timeline

\makeatletter
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@textstartabove{\tl@width-2pt}
\NewDocumentCommand\tldatelabelcventryn{O{center}O{color1}mmmmmmm}{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endyear{\tl@lastyear}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startfraction{(#3-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endfraction{(\tl@endyear-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline]{%
     \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex) rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
     \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
     \fill [#2] (0,0)
        ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [tl@startyear,yshift=5pt,anchor=#1] {#4}
        node {$\bullet$};
   }
}
{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}{#9}
}
\newcommand\tllabelcventryn[9][color1]{%
  \gdef\Argi{#1}%
  \gdef\Argii{#2}%
  \gdef\Argiii{#3}%
  \gdef\Argiv{#4}%
  \gdef\Argv{#5}%
  \gdef\Argvi{#6}%
  \gdef\Argvii{#7}%
  \gdef\Argviii{#8}%
  \gdef\Argix{#9}%
  \auxtllabelcventryn
}
\def\auxtllabelcventryn#1{%
  \gdef\Argx{#1}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endyear{ifthenelse(\Argiii==0,\tl@lastyear,\Argiii)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startfraction{(\Argii-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endfraction{(\tl@endyear-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline=0pt]{
     \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
     \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
     \fill [\Argi] (0,0)
        ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [tl@startyear,anchor=north east] {\Argiv} node [tl@startyear,above] {\Argv}
        rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width-1pt);
     \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{\Argiii} \ifdim\pgf@xa=0pt
        \shade [left color=\Argi] (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
            rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
     \else
        \fill [\Argi] (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
            rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
     \fi
     }
}
{\Argvi}{\Argvii}{\Argviii}{\Argix}{\Argx}%
}
\makeatother
%
\tltextstart[north]{\scriptsize}
\tltextend[south]{\scriptsize}

%
\firstname{C}
\familyname{N}
\title{Curriculum vit\ae{}}              
\address{}{}  
\photo[128pt]{picture}                        

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
born on .... in xxxxx

\section{school education}
\tlcventry[cyan!60!black]{2000}{2008}{test1}{test}{}{}{grade: 22}
\tlcventry[cyan!60!black]{1996}{2000}{test2}{}{}{}{test}
\section{studies}
\tllabelcventryn[cyan!60!black]{2011}{2013}{Oct 01, 2011}{today}{test3a}{}{}{}{test}

\tllabelcventry[cyan!60!black]{2011}{2013}{Oct 01, 2011--today}{test3b}{}{}{}{test}

\tldatelabelcventryn[east][cyan!60!black]{2011}{Apr 06, 2011}{Test4}{}{test}
{test}{}

\tllabelcventryn[cyan!60!black]{2009}{2011}{Dec 01,2009}{Jan 01,2011}{Test5}{}{}{}{test}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! But how can I combine it with your solution to my question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132747/questions-about-my-cv-header-and-cover-letter to suppress the final dots? I don't like the final dots.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it, I just add the part under % "Suppress final dot in \cventry" up to before the section "% New page style" starts. This works.

Comment: One last question: If I add the following entry: "\tllabelcventryn[cyan!60!black]{2000}{2008.583}{2000}{Jul 11, 2008}{Test}{Test}{}{}{grade: 1.8}" I have the problem, that the "Jul 11, 2008" is too left. So it is on the left side but not on the right side, how can I get it on the right side? See my edit in my question. Thanks a lot for your help again.

Comment: Also I want the Test4, the "Apr 06, 2011" in the same style as the others, so the "Apr 06, 2011" should be centered about the dot in the timeline, so it also shifts a bit to the right? See my second edit.

Comment: With "same style" I mean the other entries like Test5: The label is also over the timeline on the right side. I like it its okay, but I also want to have Apr 06, 2011 in the same style, so because it is in 2011 the label should also "go over" the right margin of the timeline. As the label "Jan 01, 2011$ of Test5 does.

Comment: I found a solution for my first problem: I can push the entry "Jul 11, 2008" to the right with entering the command "\hspace{2.8cm}" exactly before the Jul 11, 2008. So this works fine. Only the problem with the Apr 06, 2011 is left. Unfortunately, \hspace{2.8cm} does not work in case of the entry of the Apr 06, 2011. The label is not shifted, it stays at the same position.

Comment: @JenBohold For the reamining problem with "Apr 06, 2011", simply change the anchor from `east` to `center`; i.e., instead of `\tldatelabelcventryn[east][cyan!60!black]{2011}{Apr 06, 2011}{Test4}{}{test}
{test}{}` use `\tldatelabelcventryn[center][cyan!60!black]{2011}{Apr 06, 2011}{Test4}{}{test}
{test}{}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I will award you with the bounty when I can, this is in 2 hours.