# 'Questions about my cv and cover letter', changing formatting of template

Tags: templates, moderncv

I know I'm not supposed to post questions under others' topics, so here is my question regarding the CV and cover letter template in:

[Questions about my cv header and cover letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132747/questions-about-my-cv-header-and-cover-letter)

and here is the code that I'm trying to modify:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm,headheight=21pt} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

% Suppress final dot in \cventry
% Suppress final dot in \cventry
\renewcommand*\cventry[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    \strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
% New page style
\fancypagestyle{myfancy}{
\fancyhead[L]{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\sffamily\footnotesize
  Address Line 1\\Address Line 2}}
\fancyhead[C]{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\fixedphonesymbol\sffamily\footnotesize  555-123-456-789}}
\fancyhead[R]{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\emailsymbol\sffamily\footnotesize  abcd@tex.stackexchange.com}}
}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@myfancy
\let\ps@empty\ps@myfancy
\makeatother
\pagestyle{myfancy}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother

\firstname{Prename\\[.2ex]}
\familyname{\unskip Surname}
\title{Curriculum vitae}              
\address{}{}  
\photo[128pt]{picture}                        

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
born 99.11.999 in smallcity

\section{school education}

\cventry{1996- 2008}{Abitur}{School City}{}{}{grade: x,x}  
\cventry{1996--2000}{elementary school}{}{}{}{Grundschule somewhere}
\section{studies}

\cventry{02.10.2011-- today}{matriculation Master of Science in xxx}{}{}{}{Joint Masters Program in whatever}
\cventry{07.04.2011}{finishing of Bachelor studies}{}{}{}{grade: x,x title: Bachelor of Science whatever}
\cventry{02.12.2010-01.02.2011}{student assistant}{}{}{}{Chair of xxx  Prof. Dr. xxx \newline student assistant as a tutor of xxx}
\cventry{21.07.2008--29.09.2011}{matriculation Bachelor of Science xxx}{}{}{}{university of xxx}
\section{Bachelor thesis}
\cvline{title}{\emph{Here comes a long title}}
\cvline{supervisor}{Prof. Dr. xxxxx}
\cvline{date}{february 2011}
\cvline{grade}{1.0}

\section{languages}
\cvlanguage{german}{mother tongue}{}
\cvlanguage{english}{fluent}{}

\section{technical knowledge}

\cvline{basic}{Stata, SPSS}
\cvline{expert}{R}

\cvline{miscellaneous}{LaTex, Microsoft Office, Microsoft Dynamics} 


\clearpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[color1,line width=10pt] 
  ([yshift=-55pt]current page.north west) -- +(14cm,0pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\recipient{HR Departmnet}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State} 
\date{\today} 
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,} 
\closing{Sincerely yours,} 
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}} 

\makelettertitle 

\lipsum[1-3] 

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

Gonzalo Medina's above answer gives a lovely template, but I would like to modify the formatting under 'school education'. Right now, if I write `\cventry{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}` under 'school education', 2 is bold and 3 is in italics by default. I was wondering how to customise the all the formatting of `\cventry`. I'm not really sure how to adjust the code in Gonzalo Medina's answer because it's a little unwieldy.

Comment: Could you make the title of this question more meaningful, so other people with similar issues have a chance of finding it? Also, please include a minimal example document for people to play with, it's a bit of a hassle to have to go to another question and try to figure out which code is relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I've got it sorted :D. It's quite simple. We just have to change

```
\renewcommand*\cventry[7][.25em]{%
 \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
 {\bfseries#3}%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
 \strut%
 \ifx&#7&%
   \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

to

```
\renewcommand*\cventry[7][.25em]{%
 \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
 {#3}%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, #4}%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
 \strut%
 \ifx&#7&%
   \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
```

which means everything entered in `{}` of `\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{}` in the document body is ordinary text.

Then we can just apply whatever formatting required.