# 'Questions about my cv and cover letter' revisited, changing number of lines in address

Tags: templates, moderncv

I'm using Gonzalo Medina's answer in this question:

[Questions about my cv header and cover letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132747/questions-about-my-cv-header-and-cover-letter)

and the code is reproduced as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}                  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  
\usepackage{floatflt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm,headheight=21pt} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

% Suppress final dot in \cventry
\renewcommand*\cventry[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    \strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}

% New page style
\fancypagestyle{myfancy}{
\fancyhead[L]{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\sffamily\footnotesize
  Address Line 1\\Address Line 2}}
\fancyhead[C]{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\fixedphonesymbol\sffamily\footnotesize  555-123-456-789}}
\fancyhead[R]{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\emailsymbol\sffamily\footnotesize  abcd@tex.stackexchange.com}}
}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@myfancy
\let\ps@empty\ps@myfancy
\makeatother
\pagestyle{myfancy}

% Redefinitions of \makecvtitle, opening and closing to
% have the desired formatting for first and family names
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \def\phonesdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname}\par\smallskip\namestyle{\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % optional detailed information (rendering)
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle
\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
  \@closing\\[3em]%
  {\bfseries\@firstname\\\@lastname}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
    \\%
    \vfill%
    {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}
\renewcommand*{\makelettertitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
  % sender contact info
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%
    \raggedleft%
    \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
      {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname\\\@lastname}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
        \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}%
    \end{minipage}\\[1em]
  % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % date
  \hfill% US style
%  \\[1em]% UK style
  \@date\\[2em]% US informal style: "January 1, 1900"; UK formal style: "01/01/1900"
  % opening
  \raggedright%
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}

\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother

\firstname{Prename}
\familyname{Surname}
\title{Curriculum vitae}              
\address{}{}  
\photo[128pt]{picture}                        

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
born 99.11.999 in smallcity

\section{school education}

\cventry{1996- 2008}{Abitur}{School City}{}{}{grade: x,x}  
\cventry{1996--2000}{elementary school}{}{}{}{Grundschule somewhere}
\section{studies}

\cventry{02.10.2011-- today}{matriculation Master of Science in xxx}{}{}{}{Joint Masters Program in whatever}
\cventry{07.04.2011}{finishing of Bachelor studies}{}{}{}{grade: x,x title: Bachelor of Science whatever}
\cventry{02.12.2010-01.02.2011}{student assistant}{}{}{}{Chair of xxx  Prof. Dr. xxx \newline student assistant as a tutor of xxx}
\cventry{21.07.2008--29.09.2011}{matriculation Bachelor of Science xxx}{}{}{}{university of xxx}
\section{Bachelor thesis}
\cvline{title}{\emph{Here comes a long title}}
\cvline{supervisor}{Prof. Dr. xxxxx}
\cvline{date}{february 2011}
\cvline{grade}{1.0}

\section{languages}
\cvlanguage{german}{mother tongue}{}
\cvlanguage{english}{fluent}{}

\section{technical knowledge}

\cvline{basic}{Stata, SPSS}
\cvline{expert}{R}

\cvline{miscellaneous}{LaTex, Microsoft Office, Microsoft Dynamics} 


\clearpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[color1,line width=10pt] 
  ([yshift=-55pt]current page.north west) -- +(14cm,0pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\recipient{HR Departmnet}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State} 
\date{\today} 
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,} 
\closing{Sincerely yours,} 
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}} 

\makelettertitle 

\lipsum[1-3] 

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

I am trying to change the address field so that it shows my name, street, suburb, city, country all on separate lines. I know that I have to change these blocks of code, but how?

```
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
  \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
  \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
\end{tabular}
```

and

```
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}%
    \raggedleft%
    \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
      {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname {} \@lastname}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
        \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}%
    \end{minipage}\\[1em]
```

I've tried doing it the logical way and added

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresssuburb}}{}{\makenewline\@addresssuburb%
```

between the lines related to street and city, but I get an error:

```
File ended while scanning use of \@argdef
```

(Am I just being dumb?) The idea is to put `\address{street name}{suburb}{city}{country}` in the document body so that my name, street, suburb, city, country would be shown on the top right-hand side of the first page of the cover letter and cv.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using an older version of class `moderncv`. You used the command `\makecvtitlenamewidth` that has been renamed with current version 2.0.0 of `moderncv` to `\makecvheadnamewidth`.

You can add an new definiton of `\makecvtitlenamewidth` (see line 91 in the following MWE, important changes marked with `<=====`) or you have to rename all `\makecvtitlenamewidth` to `\makecvheadnamewidth`:

```
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}} % <======= line 91 ======================
```

Then you have to add the using od the new optional parameter `{suburb}` for `\address`:

```
\address{street and number}{suburb}{postcode city}{country} % <======== line 161 ===================
```

and of course you have to change the definition of the command `\address` that your new parameter `suburb` can be used:

```
\makeatletter % <======= line 42 ========================================
\RenewDocumentCommand{\address}{mG{}G{}G{}}{\def\@addressstreet{#1}\def\@addresssuburb{#2}\def\@addresscity{#3}\def\@addresscountry{#4}}
\makeatother
```

(the commands are needed here because of the use of `@` in the names of variables).

At last you have to change the output of the adrress for cv:

```
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}% <====== line 62 =======================
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresssuburb}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresssuburb}% <======================
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
```

and the letter:

```
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}% <============= line 121 ==============
    \raggedleft%
    \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
      {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname\\\@lastname}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresssuburb}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresssuburb}% <======================
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
        \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}%
    \end{minipage}\\[1em]
```

If you want to change the order of `city` and `suburb` just change the variables `\@addresscity` and `\@addresssuburb`.

So with the complete MWE for the current version 2.0.0 of `moderncv`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv} 

\moderncvtheme[green]{classic}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=2cm,right=1cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm,headheight=21pt} 

\usepackage{lipsum} 

% Suppress final dot in \cventry
\renewcommand*\cventry[7][.25em]{%
  \cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    \strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}

% New page style
\fancypagestyle{myfancy}{
\fancyhead[L]{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\sffamily\footnotesize
  Address Line 1\\Address Line 2}}
\fancyhead[C]{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\fixedphonesymbol\sffamily\footnotesize  555-123-456-789}}
\fancyhead[R]{\parbox[t]{.3333\textwidth}{\emailsymbol\sffamily\footnotesize  abcd@tex.stackexchange.com}}
}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@myfancy
\let\ps@empty\ps@myfancy
\makeatother
\pagestyle{myfancy}

% defines one's address (optional)
% usage: \address{<street>}{<city>}{<country>}
%\address{street and number}{suburb}{postcode city}{country}
% where the <city> and <country> arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\address}{mG{}G{}G{}}{\def\@addressstreet{#1}\def\@addresssuburb{#2}\def\@addresscity{#3}\def\@addresscountry{#4}}
\makeatother

% Redefinitions of \makecvtitle, opening and closing to
% have the desired formatting for first and family names
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \def\phonesdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \def\socialsdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
    \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}% <====== line 62 =======================
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresssuburb}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresssuburb}% <======================
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}%
    }%
  }%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}} % <======= line 91 ======================
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname}\par\smallskip\namestyle{\@lastname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % optional detailed information (rendering)
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle
\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
  \@closing\\[3em]%
  {\bfseries\@firstname\\\@lastname}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
    \\%
    \vfill%
    {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}}
\renewcommand*{\makelettertitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
  % sender contact info
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}% <============= line 121 ==============
    \raggedleft%
    \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
      {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname\\\@lastname}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresssuburb}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresssuburb}% <======================
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
      \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
        \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}%
    \end{minipage}\\[1em]
  % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % date
  \hfill% US style
%  \\[1em]% UK style
  \@date\\[2em]% US informal style: "January 1, 1900"; UK formal style: "01/01/1900"
  % opening
  \raggedright%
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother

\firstname{Prename}
\familyname{Surname}
\title{Curriculum vitae}              
\address{street and number}{suburb}{postcode city}{country} % <======== line 161 ===================
\photo[128pt]{example-image-a}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle 

born 99.11.999 in smallcity

\section{school education}

\cventry{1996- 2008}{Abitur}{School City}{}{}{grade: x,x}  
\cventry{1996--2000}{elementary school}{}{}{}{Grundschule somewhere}
\section{studies}

\cventry{02.10.2011-- today}{matriculation Master of Science in xxx}{}{}{}{Joint Masters Program in whatever}
\cventry{07.04.2011}{finishing of Bachelor studies}{}{}{}{grade: x,x title: Bachelor of Science whatever}
\cventry{02.12.2010-01.02.2011}{student assistant}{}{}{}{Chair of xxx  Prof. Dr. xxx \newline student assistant as a tutor of xxx}
\cventry{21.07.2008--29.09.2011}{matriculation Bachelor of Science xxx}{}{}{}{university of xxx}
\section{Bachelor thesis}
\cvline{title}{\emph{Here comes a long title}}
\cvline{supervisor}{Prof. Dr. xxxxx}
\cvline{date}{february 2011}
\cvline{grade}{1.0}

\section{languages}
\cvlanguage{german}{mother tongue}{}
\cvlanguage{english}{fluent}{}

\section{technical knowledge}

\cvline{basic}{Stata, SPSS}
\cvline{expert}{R}

\cvline{miscellaneous}{LaTex, Microsoft Office, Microsoft Dynamics} 


\clearpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[color1,line width=10pt] 
  ([yshift=-55pt]current page.north west) -- +(14cm,0pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\recipient{HR Departmnet}{Corporation\\123 Pleasant Lane\\12345 City, State} 
\date{\today} 
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,} 
\closing{Sincerely yours,} 
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}} 

\makelettertitle 

\lipsum[1-3] 

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image]